# Java: if statement with not equals breaking the program

Tags: java

I can't figure out why my code isn't working.

It appears to be breaking around the if not equal to yes or no area.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");
    name = user_input.next();

    System.out.println("");

    String name_answer;
    System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ". Is this correct? (yes/no)");
    name_answer = user_input.next();

    System.out.println("");

    if (!name_answer.equals("yes" + "no")) { 
        System.out.println("Answer not valid. Please input again.");
        name_answer = user_input.next();
        while (!name_answer.equals("yes" + "no")) {
            System.out.println("Answer not valid. Please input again.");
            name_answer = user_input.next(); } }

    if (name_answer.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you, " + name + ". Please proceed to the next question.");
    } else if (name_answer.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("Please reinput your name correctly.");
        while (name_answer.equals("no")) {
            String name_again;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("What is your correct name?");
            name_again = user_input.next();

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Your name is " + name_again + ". Is this correct? (yes/no)");
            name_answer = user_input.next();  }
```

If i comment out the not-equals block of code (displayed below), the program works. However, with the block of code in, the program breaks.

```
    if (!name_answer.equals("yes" + "no")) { 
        System.out.println("Answer not valid. Please input again.");
        name_answer = user_input.next();
        while (!name_answer.equals("yes" + "no")) {
            System.out.println("Answer not valid. Please input again.");
            name_answer = user_input.next(); } }
```

My goal is to have any answer not equal to "yes" or "no" be reinputted while a "yes" or "no" brings the program to another step. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you think `"yes" + "no"` means? What do you think "breaks" means?

Comment: In essence, what your code is asking your **if** and **while**  loop conditions to check for is: If the String variable named ***name_answer*** does not equal "yesno". I don't believe this is your intent. Read up on the [Logical AND](https://www.javatpoint.com/operators-in-java) operator and you might also benefit from reading about the [String.equalsIgnoreCase()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm) method.

Comment: What if someone inputs "no" and then inputs gibberish the next time you ask them? Why did you hard-code the first iteration of your while loop outside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical problem with your code is that you're using concatenation instead of logical operators. `"yes" + "no"` evaluates to `"yesno"`, which will probably never match your input string.

More fundamentally, the problem is that you're trying to bundle two boolean evaluations into one. Logically, you want to proceed if the answer is not "yes" **and** the answer is not "no". In Java syntax:

```
if (!name_answer.equals("yes") && !name_answer.equals("no")) {
```

If you want to test multiple values at a time, you can use this shortcut:

```
if (!Arrays.asList("yes", "no", "foo", "bar").contains(name_answer)) {
```

Comment: The whole flow of the code could do with re-visiting I think